# Asp.Net boilerplate,, How to Move boilerplate project to another Computer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ef-code-first, aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate

I was working on ASP.Net boilerplate framework and now that machine is not available where i was working, But i have backup on my Google drive. How i can use that backup properly? Database creation , project running etc???
I am getting error on Enable-Migrations and Update Database Commands

```
Exception calling "LoadFrom" with "1" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly 'file:///F:\Qubit 
 Systems\ShipperBuyerV1\module-zero-template-2.1.1\src\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.PowerShell.Utility.dll' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. 
    (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)"
 At F:\Qubit Systems\ShipperBuyerV1\module-zero-template-2.1.1\src\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:780 char:5
+     $utilityAssembly = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom((Join-P ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileLoadException

 You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
  At F:\Qubit Systems\ShipperBuyerV1\module-zero-template-2.1.1\src\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:781 char:5
 +     $dispatcher = $utilityAssembly.CreateInstance(
 +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

 Exception calling "CreateInstanceFrom" with "8" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly 'file:///F:\Qubit 
   Systems\ShipperBuyerV1\module-zero-template-2.1.1\src\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.PowerShell.dll' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception 
 from HRESULT: 0x80131515)"
    At F:\Qubit Systems\ShipperBuyerV1\module-zero-template-2.1.1\src\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:809 char:5
 +     $domain.CreateInstanceFrom(
 +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileLoadException
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you should do:

1. Download the project from your Google drive
2. Open in Visual Studio
3. Run Database-Update (Make sure the Entity Framework project is selected in the Nuget Package Manager.

That is all you need to do to get. All you will lose is the data in your previous database on the unavailable machine.

Comment: Ok @Sleek let me check

Comment: Here is the error : on Applying command Update-Database it is giving "Could not load file or assembly"

Comment: Try building the project first. Does it succeed?

Comment: Check Edit version of the Question i pasted the Error Sir @Sleek

Comment: Try this: Navigate to `EntityFramework.PowerShell.Utility.dll`, right-lick on it, choose Properties, and remove the Read Only check mark. Also, you may need to unblock it using the same process (Right Click > Properties > Unblock). After this, try building again to see if `EntityFramework.PowerShell.Utility.dll` throws this same error. If not, unblock all the other DLLs that throw this error.

Comment: Where this file exist? EntityFramework.PowerShell.Utility.dll ?? Sir @Sleek

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is to create a repo in Git, add you project in it. On there PC run git clone on the desired path.

Refer [Setting up git repo](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/setting-up-a-repository)